# Css display in the back

Tags: css

I want this image 1 looks like the image 2.

image 1

[image]

image 2

[image]

Here's my css of top-message class name which is in red color.

```
.top-message{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1030;
  height:22px; 
  width:100%;
  margin-top:-2px;
}
```

Comment: `top-message` class `z-index` should be greater than the sidebar `z-index`

Answer (score 1):

It is coming to the top because of

```
z-index: 1030;
```

[Z-Index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

You need to make sure that the dropdown menu `z-index` is higher than `top.message`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `z-index` of the sidebar is more than the `z-index` of the top-message. If it is and still doesn't work; try giving `position: relative;` to the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-message{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 1030;
  height:22px; 
  width:100%;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have containers for each of the elements as the others have said you should make sure the reddish alert has a z-index value less than that of the menu/nav bar on the left. In my opinion, I would set an outer container with an absolute position and set the remaining inner containers that make up the top nav bar, red alert message, and left side menu with a relative position. Make sure the z-index numbers you set start with the initial value of 0 and increment by 1 as you "cascade" down the code.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)